# How can I add a label to specific bars (not all) in a matplotlib bar?

Tags: python, matplotlib, bar-chart

I have built a bar chart that is showing value counts for every day in a year - I want to add labels to specific days, is this possible? I can only find examples where this applies to all. This is my code:

```
daychart = data.groupby(['Day'], as_index=False, sort=False).agg(Count=('Day','size'))
plt.figure(figsize=(20,4))
matplotlib.pyplot.bar(x="Day", height="Count", data=daychart)
plt.show()
```

This is what it looks like so far:

[image]

I want to (for example) label *just* 24 November (Thanksgiving) - How would I got about this?

Thank you :)

Answer (score 1):

Hopefully this helps, first get a basic date for any year of Jan 1, then this Jan 1 + the corresponding value from 0 to 365 and then display back the value without year. change the x-axis to this value instead of 0-365. Below is the code to get the job done.

```
import pandas as pd
d = { 'day_in_year': [n for n in range(0,365)]}
df = pd.DataFrame(d)

date = pd.DatetimeIndex( df['day_in_year'].iloc[0:1] ).values 
df['date'] = df['day_in_year'].apply( lambda col: (date + pd.Timedelta(col, "d"))[0]) 
df['date'] = df['date'].dt.strftime('%d %B')
df
```

---

Btw, if you also want to get the holiday on x-axis below code may help, web-scrape data from 'https://www.officeholidays.com/countries/usa/2022', the year can change on below code, you may need to install bs4 (BeautifulSoup for web scraping)

---

```
import requests 
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd

d = { 'day_in_year': [n for n in range(0,365)]}
df = pd.DataFrame(d)

date = pd.DatetimeIndex( df['day_in_year'].iloc[0:1] ).values 
df['date'] = df['day_in_year'].apply( lambda col: (date + pd.Timedelta(col, "d"))[0]) 
df['date_clean'] = df['date'].dt.strftime('%d %B')
df['date_join_key'] = df['date'].dt.strftime('%b %d')

year = '2022'
web_url = f'https://www.officeholidays.com/countries/usa/{year}'
req = requests.get( web_url)
if req.status_code== 200:    raw_data = BeautifulSoup(req.text,'html.parser')
    
data_table = raw_data.find_all('table',{'class':'country-table'})

df_dic = {'date':[],'holiday':[]}

df_dic.get('date').append( [value.text for value in data_table[0].find_all( 'time' , {'itemprop':'startDate'} )])
df_dic.get('holiday').append( [value.text for value in data_table[0].find_all( 'a' , {'class':'country-listing'} )])

df_dic['date']=df_dic.get('date')[0]
df_dic['holiday']=df_dic.get('holiday')[0]
df_holiday = pd.DataFrame( df_dic )
df_holiday['holiday'] = ' - ' + df_holiday['holiday']

df = df.merge( df_holiday , left_on = ['date_join_key'] , right_on = ['date'] , how = 'left')

df['Final_X_Axis'] = df['date_clean'] + df['holiday'].fillna('')

df
```

Comment: Thanks for this, not sure if I am following - Can you tell me how I would add a label for 24 November (day 328 for instance)?

Comment: when you mention label, do you mean the holiday indicator? if you're referring the holiday indicator then I simply web scrape extracting the holiday data from "https://www.officeholidays.com/countries/usa/2022" and left join it back to the original data frame.